# PHP how to remove author metadata from docx

Tags: php, zip, metadata, docx, php-ziparchive

In PHP I've to remove the author metadata from a DOCX file. First of all, I've unzip the document and after I've edit the author metadata setting it empty using an XML reader library.

```
$file = 'document.docx';
$filename = 'path/'.$file;

// Unzip the docx
$unzipped = md5($filename);

if (file_exists($unzipped)) {
    rmdir($unzipped);
    mkdir($unzipped);
}

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($filename);
if ($res === true) {
    extractFolder($zip, "word/media", $unzipped);
    $zip->extractTo($unzipped); 
    $zip->close();
} else {
    die("The docx file appears to be corrupt (i.e. it can't be opened using Zip).\n");
}
```

The problem occurs when I tried to re-zip the document. In fact, when the re-zip is done, the docx file seems to be corrupted when I open it in Word.

```
create_docx($unzipped,'_zips/'.$file );
```

How can I modify the author metadata (setting the document anonymous) and save the correct docx file?

Comment: `rrmdir` ? surely that ought to be `rmdir`!

Comment: yes sorry, it's my mistake, thanks! However, I don't think that this is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php, but I assume the problem is that you have to compress inside the folder $unzipped,  NOT the folder itself. So a kind of recursive "$unzipped/*" as source instead of "$unzipped".